# powershell question relating to selecting a string

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I have a problem in a script where i need to select a string and put it into a file.
I need to use the "Get-Website" cmmdlet in powershell to pull the ID

right now i am using Get-Website *sitename |fl ID
now the output comes along like "id : 15"
i need to drop this down to sjust the ID number and use it elsewhere in the script to then inject it into a .txt file so that a perl script can come along and use it for stats

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$val = ($string -split ": ")[1]
```

Comment: that does not seem to work, 

even when running the output of Get-Website via a | to it it errors on the $string

Comment: @BeStRaFe: `$string = Get-Website *sitename |fl ID` then the line above. Or `$val = ((Get-Website *sitename |fl ID) -split ": ")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Website *sitename | Foreach-Object {$_.Id}
```